# C++ text menu: writing, reading, and sorting data

Tags: c++

So my assignment is to create multiple classes for a Person, Name, ID #, Address, and Phone #.

Name makes up: First, Middle, and Last name.
ID # makes up: 9 digits.
Address makes up: street, city, state, and 5 digit zip code.
Phone # makes up: 3 digit area code and 7 digit number.
Person makes up: a full Name (First, Middle, Last), an Address, a Phone # (area code, and number), and a ID # (9 digit number).

I have accomplished all of this.  My problem is we are also supposed to make a menu, to specify how many people the user wishes to type in, where they want to save the file, if they want to read or write to a file specified by the user, and being able to sort the people by name (last, first, or middle) or by ID #, and save the sorted list to a user specified file.

I have all the code written, but my write function is not working for some reason.  What happens is I run the program, the menu I created pops up.  I select '1' enter the file, then the menu pops up again, and I select '2' to make sure it cant read since there is nothing in the specific file I am testing with. Next, I select '3' to write People to the user specified file.  It prompts me for how many People I want to enter and I enter a number (2).  Then the prompt for typing in the first name pops up and I get some error saying "an unhandled win32 exception occured" in my project .exe...

Here is my code:

```
//global variables
char filename[256];
fstream file2 (filename);

int r;
Person * stuArrPtr=new Person[r];

int w;
Person * stuArrPtr2=new Person[w];

//global functions
void WriteUserFile () {
//write as many ppl as specified to a file...
// int w;
 cout << "How many students would you like to enter?: ";
 cin  >> w;

// Person * stuArrPtr2=new Person[w];
 if (!file2.is_open ()) {
  cout << "File did not open" << endl;
  file2.clear ();
  file2.open (filename, ios_base::out);
  file2.close ();
  file2.open (filename, ios_base::out | ios_base::in);

 }
 else {
  for (int i = 0; i < w/*!file2.eof ()*/; i++) {
   stuArrPtr2[i].InputPerson();
   if (strcmp(stuArrPtr2[i].PersonNam.GetFirst(), "EOF") != 0)
    stuArrPtr2[i].Display (file2);
  }
 }
 cout << endl;
// delete [] stuArrPtr2;
}

void Menu () {
 int option;
 do {
  //display menu
  cout << " Type '1' - to open a file for reading or writing" << endl << endl;
  cout << " Type '2' - to read from the file you specified in '1'" << endl << endl;
  cout << " Type '3' - to write from the file you specified in '1'" << endl << endl;
  cout << " Type '4' - sort students by last name" << endl << endl;
  cout << " Type '5' - sort students by first name" << endl << endl;
  cout << " Type '6' - sort students by middle name" << endl << endl;
  cout << " Type '7' - sort students by ID number" << endl << endl;
  cout << " Type '8' - exit" << endl << endl;
//  cout << " Enter appropriate number here: [ ]\b\b";
  cout << " Enter appropriate number here: ";
  cin >> option;

  switch(option) {
   case 1:
    cout << "you entered option 1" << endl;
    OpenUserFile ();
    break;
   case 2:
    cout << "you entered option 2" << endl;
    ReadUserFile ();
    break;
   case 3:
    cout << "you entered option 3" << endl;
    WriteUserFile ();
    break;
   case 4:
    cout << "you entered option 4" << endl;
    SortLastName ();
    break;
   case 5:
    cout << "you entered option 5" << endl;
    SortFirstName ();
    break;
   case 6:
    cout << "you entered option 6" << endl;
    SortMiddleName ();
    break;
   case 7:
    cout << "you entered option 7" << endl;
    SortIDNumber ();
    break;
   case 8:
    cout << "you entered option 8" << endl; //exit
    delete [] stuArrPtr;
    delete [] stuArrPtr2;
    break;
   default:
    cout << "you screwed up, no big deal, just try again!" << endl;
  } //end switch
  //if (option == 6) {
  // break;
  //}
 } while (option != 8);
// system("pause"); 
}

void main () {
Menu ();
}
/////////////////END OF CODE///////
```

Sorry the code is so long, and any help is very, very much appreciated!

Comment: Could you reformate the code? Just indent it by 4 spaces.

Comment: could you please re-format your code that at least the code part is in 1 block? Thanks

Comment: This is how you edit your code: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: you might like to cut the code down to the smallest piece that isn't working - you say that the write function isn't working and talk about a menu but you don't say how the write function isn't working. Why does it fail? What are the symptoms that tell you it isn't working?

Comment: @nick: also would be nice if you dumped only the write function and not the whole stuff

Comment: ok I took out all the headers and the openfile function... hope that helps make it more readable... Also, I added what excatly happens when I run the program and try to execute the write fucntion...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem with your code are the first few lines.

```
int w;
Person * stuArrPtr2=new Person[w];
```

At program startup w is most probably initialized with 0. So you create an array of zero Persons.
The moment you call `stuArrPtr2[i].InputPerson()` which should be `stuArrPtr2[i]->InputPerson()` by the way, you try to access a member function of an non existing object.

What you will have to do is create new Person objects depending on the number you just entered like `stuArrPtr2 = new Person[w]` within the function `WriteUserFile()`.

Cheers
Holger

Comment: Ok, thank you sooo much!! That fixed it, and makes sense to me now that you pointed it out.  However, now I have 1 more small problem.  When I run the WriteUserFile() I enter the number of student, and it skips the first prompt (enter first name).  So the first prompt I can type in is the Middle name.  Why would it be skipping that first prompt (enter first name)?

Comment: since I don't know what the function InputPerson() looks like it's quite hard to tell what goes wrong ;-)

Comment: well thanks for all your help i fixed this problem with an additional cin.getline before the WriteUserFile() and that fixed the problem!

Answer (score 0):

what  `stuArrPtr2[i].Display (file2);` is doing ?

also you don't have a better way to remember the last person ?

```
if (strcmp(stuArrPtr2[i].PersonNam.GetFirst(), "EOF") != 0)
```

like number of item in the array or chained list.

Comment: stuArrPtr2[i].Display (file2);    displays the Person data to file2 which is the input file specified by the user.

And no I'm not sure how else to remember the last Person...

Comment: so basically  stuArrPtr2[i].Display (file2);  writes the Person data to the user specified input file...

Answer (score 0):

Some hints:

- use std::string, not arrays of char
- do not create objects using new unless absolutely necessary
- learn about scope - your file stream shoud not be global
- main must return an int
- think before writing code

Comment: Well you are wrong about main, my teacher told us to do it the way I have done it above, and the way you are reffering to is considered old and bad practice... You cannot use std::string without too much effort because many of the functions I am using rquire "char *" so its really my only option...  I understand the scope of my file stream should not be global, but it is the only way my code will work and I do not have time to write another class...
And I really appreciate your last comment, what kind of comment is that!?

Comment: I don't suppose it has occured to you that your teacher might be wrong?

Comment: No, it doesnt occur to me because this is the second teacher I have had that has told me this.  Also, when I visited colleges a few months ago and sat in on multiple c++ classes, all the main functions were written the way I wrote above...  Even if my teacher was wrong, why does it compile and the code inside it run?

Comment: Well it should occur to you, because your teachers are indeed wrong. C++ is not defined by your teachers, or by the compiler that you happen to use (I'd guess Microsoft's) but by the C++ Standard, an ISO document. And this specifies very clearly that main() must have the return type int.

Comment: The main() function returns an int. Always. Whether C++ or C.
See http://c-faq.com/ansi/index.html items 11.12 through 11.16.